# Secrurity rules real time database firebase 3 differents groups of users (Prenium, Access, Free )

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I would like to give access data prenium only to user prenium, data access only to user access and data free to user free

I have written this security rules which make the job if we enter a specific 'user_uid'.
However i would like to make the test for a list of users

```js
{
  "rules": {
    "data_prenium": {
     ".read":"root.child('users').child('user_uid').child('status').val() === 'prenium'" ,
    },
      
    "data_free": {
     ".read":"root.child('users').child('user_uid').child('status').val() === 'free'" ,
    },

    "data_access": {
     ".read":"root.child('users').child('user_uid').child('status').val() === 'access'" ,
    },
      
     "users": {
      "$userId": {
        // grants write access to the owner of this user account
        // whose uid must exactly match the key ($user_id)
        ".read": "$userId === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$userId === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Like that for example :

```js
{
  "rules": {
    "data_prenium": {
     ".read":"root.child('users').children().keys().child('status').val() === 'prenium'" ,
    },
      
    "data_free": {
     ".read":"root.child('users').children().keys().child('status').val() === 'free'" ,
    },

    "data_access": {
     ".read":"root.child('users').children().keys().child('status').val() === 'access'" ,
    },
      
     "users": {
      "$userId": {
        // grants write access to the owner of this user account
        // whose uid must exactly match the key ($user_id)
        ".read": "$userId === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$userId === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Somebody know how to do that ?

Comment: Unrelated to the problem (which I answered below): you have a spelling mistake in `prenium`, which should be spelled `premium`. While it won't cause problems on the code level, I recommend changing it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check the status for the user that is trying to access the data, you can use the `auth.uid` variable that is automatically populated when you use Firebase Authentication with the Realtime Database.

So:

```
".read": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('status').val() === 'prenium'",
```